# Is there a term for the case when the author does not see the flaws of their own project?

Tags: phrase-requests

Lets say you are writing a book, making a cardboard game or composing a music.

After a while you are so invested into your creation and know it so well from inside and out. You can no longer see the major flaws in the design or errors you made. And only way is to get a feedback from other people who can give you a fresh perspective.

Is there a term for this "author's blindness"?

Comment: *Writer's blindspot*, perhaps, but I cannot find a citation.

Answer (score 1):

You  are **too close** and need to **step back** to get some perspective.

> **step back**
>   2. To withdraw from something, especially to consider it from a wider perspective: 
>   *Let's step back from the project for a moment and admire all that we have accomplished. Rather than arguing about every detail, they should step back and determine what is really important*.
>   [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+step+back)